# Update paused due to failure or early termination of task. OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:2… [DOCKER]

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I tried to update my service with

`sudo docker service update result --network-add backend --publish-add 5001`

And got the error stating

```
result
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: starting container failed: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:2… 
service update paused: update paused due to failure or early termination of task gyovus3crd23v3wb22m1lbxf5
```

However I stopped the process while service `result` was being created because it took long time. Is there any way to complete the process of creation now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something in your change is causing those containers to crash.

It could be your command option order. The service name always goes at the end. If you look at `docker service update --help` you'll see it say:

`Usage: docker service update [OPTIONS] SERVICE`

Start a new update cycle by fixing the command:

`sudo docker service update --network-add backend --publish-add 5001 result`

Comment: Hey @bret Thanks for the help! What a co-incidence, I faced this issue while attempting the assignment in your course on Udemy! :D It's a great one.

Comment: That. is. amazing. hah!!

Comment: hi @BretFisher. Is there no way to check logs (if possible) of the replicas that failed to start? So I would know which command failed. Because in my case, I was able to update 3/5 replicas but encountered the same experience of "early termination of task". Btw, i'm watching your tutorial too.

Comment: A `docker service logs` command won't show you why a container won't start, because it's only the output of the app inside the container. You can inspect the *tasks* in the service to see what their exit error was, but first get their task ID with `docker service ps <servicename>` then `docker inspect <taskid>`

Answer (score 5):

Got the same error when using docker swarm and worker didn't have enough disc space to download the image to deploy.

Solution: login to worker using ssh and run `docker system prune -f` to remove old images.

Answer (score 1):

An app inside the docker container may cause some error and it results in docker exited which leads to rollback. So, keep an eye on the dockers' list. When a new docker container appears with starting `starting` state, check the logs for this container. In my case, java app was crashing, I found out by checking logs.